# How can I achieve this type of shadow with PS only

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, design-principles

I tried the black to transparent grading within a rectangle, but I never got that smooth of a transition. I don't know why, but my attempts are s***

[image]

Comment: Hi Julian, thanks for your question. Could you tell us what you tried that didn't work? Always good to show some effort, and your chances for a good answer increase. I did a quick test on my computer and it looks like a basic black-to-transparent gradient on 20% opacity.

Comment: As I said, I tried a graded rectangle, but I didn't think opacity was the way to go here. Did you grade from a straight black? I started with a lighter black, but that was probably because I didn't reduce the opacity.

Comment: It says what I tried, why the down-vote! There is no use posting a picture of a graded rectangle.

Comment: Yea I used 100% RGB black to 0% opacity. I then lowered the layer to 20% but maybe 12% would be a closer match. The reason we ask you to post your attempt is so we can evaluate where you're going wrong in your design process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to know is how to make the right gradient, set it to the following, you can just copy my values and adjust to your preference:

[image]

Comment: How can I "select" an image with the gradient tool? Is that possible? Maybe its because I don't understand the beginning, but why do I rotate the image?

Comment: I'll make this idiot-proof gimme a second

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know you could reduce opacity.

Comment: @Julian I had to learn it too by try and error ;)